# Memory error c++ private int

Tags: c++, class, memory

I'm doing a project where I have to use a private int called `numberOfMatches`.
This is the code in the class Player in *player.h*:

```
    int getnumberOfMatches(){ return numberOfMatches; }
    void setnumberOfMatches(int numb){ numberOfMatches = numb; }

private:
    int numberOfMatches;
```

When I'm trying to set the number on `numberOfMatches`, its value doesn't change.

```
int amount = 10;
Player* team = new Player(amount);
for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
{
    int matches = x;
    team[x].setnumberOfMatches(matches);
}
```

But if I use `team[0].setNumberOfMatches(matches);` it changes the value.
When I add breakpoints, I see that in the team[x] case, it says:

> ```
> "<Unable to read memory>" on numberOfMatches.
> ```

This is not the case when using `team[0].set()`.

Anyone has an idea about what might be wrong?

Comment: Why are you using a pointer and `new Player`?

Comment: In the original code there's a bunch of other things when doing Player* team = new Player[amount]. It's originally reading in a string from a textfile, converting it to int and then giving us amount*team

Comment: new Player(amount) does not allocate amount Players.

Comment: Still, this is not the problem. there is nothing wrong with team. I've tried it and it does work. The problem is with numberOfMatches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code

```
Player* team = new Player(amount);
```

allocates **one** Player object.

This code accesses Player objects that were never allocated (when x is greater than zero):

```
for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
{
 int matches = x;
 team[x].setnumberOfMatches(matches);
}
```